# I try to install mysql on debian server but get an error i don't know how to solve

Tags: mysql, installation, debian

I try to install MySQL on my Debian machine(11.3) but I get an error when I try to install mysql-server. here are the previous commands I had used before.

apt update

apt install gnupg

wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb

dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb

apt-get update

now when I try 'apt-get install mysql-community-server' I get this error: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Collides with: virtual-mysql-client-core
mariadb-server-core-10.5 : Collides with: virtual-mysql-server-core

E: Error: Interruptions caused by pkgProblemResolver::Resolve; this could have been caused by withheld packets.

 I don't know what to do, I'm relatively new to Linux. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should remove mariadb before installing mysql (why not keep mariadb? it is better integrated). You are using `dpkg` which it is a low lever tool, which will not remove packages or install dependencies, just complaining. And I recommend you not to use dpkg for such cases. You will miss security updates on a core component.

Comment: thanks for the answer and how can I do this ?

Comment: If you have no idea on what I wrote, just keep mariadb (provided by Debian). MariaDB should be compatible with mysql (and it is programmed by some of the original founders of mysql). Get experience, and later you may want to reconsider and change engine. But do not do too much at same time: it will create just confusion.

Comment: I used aptitude for the installation with it, it worked fine thanks